# Derived functor and natural transformation

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $A$ and $B$ be two categories.

Let $F_1, F_2$ be  functors from $A$ to $B$ and there is a natural transformation $\eta$ from $F_1$ to $F_2$.

Now let $G$ be another functor from $B$ to $B$.

Now, there is a natural transformation from $R^iG \circ F_1$ to $R^iG \circ F_2$. Why does this map through $R^i(G \circ F_1)$, i.e it can be written as $R^iG \circ F_1 \to R^i(G \circ F_1) \to R^iG \circ F_2$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $G:B \to B$

Comment: What is the map $R^i(G\circ F_1)\to R^iF\circ F_2$ ? The natural maps are $R^i(G\circ F_1)\to R^i(G\circ F_2)\leftarrow R^iG\circ F_2$.